# output char* to std::string C++

Tags: c++, xml, string, char

So given:

```
struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};
```

`char* memory` holds a curl return, XML doc.

I am doing:

```
if(chunk.memory) {
    std::cout << "char size is " << sizeof(chunk.memory) << std::endl;
    std::string s = "";
    for (int c = 0; c<sizeof(chunk.memory); c++) {
        s.push_back(chunk.memory[c]);
    }
    std::cout << "s: " << s.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

I am only getting back `<?xm`

So `sizeof()` I think is return the total bytes in the char*

How do I get what the actual value is a `char*`. So basically the whole curl return. Which is 5 lines of XML?

Comment: `sizeof` on a `char *` will return the size of the pointer, not the number of characters in the string. Use `strlen(chunk.memory)` to get the string length (assuming its null-terminated). And there's no need to `push_back` each character individually, `std::string` has a constructor that accepts `char const *` to a null terminated string. `std::string s(chunk.memory);` will suffice. If it's not null terminated, use `s(chunk.memory, str_length);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(chunk.memory)` will give always you size of a pointer which in your case seems to be 4. That's why you see only 4 characters in your std::string.

If your curl return or whatever else is terminated by `\0`, then you can directly do the following

```
std::string s(chunk.memory);
```

If your char * is not terminated by `\0`, then you need to know the length of the string - you cannot use `sizeof(chunk.memory)` for this. If your chunk.size contains the correct size, then you can use

```
std::string s(chunk.memory, chunk.size);
```

Comment: you might want to suggest `strlen(chunk.memory)`?

Comment: Also, if `MemoryStruct` is created by his code he could just use a `std::string` there in first place.

Comment: Actually you probably don't want to use strlen because the xml parser is returning a small memory chunk that will not be null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

**std::string** constructor can accept **char*** and data length ([see the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)); Example:

```
  std::string s(chunk.memory, chunk.size);
```

So container will pre-allocate need space for your string and initialize with it.

Answer (score 2):

In `MemoryStruct` `memory` is the pointer to the first returned character and `size` is the number of characters returned. You want to initialize a string with this data so you will need to do:

```
s.assign(chunk.memory, chunk.size);
```